# Is there any problem with this code to update database values in MS Access?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

My form has a DataGridView on which, if I click on a row, the row details get placed in corresponding controls on the form. Then I can do some changes on these controls and click the button Update.  Surprisingly, the code does not do any changes to the database. I am wondering then, is there any problem in this code? Here is the Update button code of my application.

```
Private Sub UpdateButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles updateButton.Click

    Try
        Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Tukabakoma.mdb;")
            conn.Open()
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Update Members set [Name]=@name,Middlename=@midname,Surname=@sname,ContactNumber=@contnum,Address=@address,DOB=@dob,Gender=@gender,[Status]=@status,JoinDate=@jd,POB=@pob,[Guardian Name]=@guardname,[Guardian Surname]=@guardsname,Relationship=@rel,GuardNumber=@gcontnum where TKBS_ID=@tkbsid", conn)
            With cmd.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("@tkbsid", tkbsIDTextBox.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@name", nameTextBox.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@midname", middleNameTextBox.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@sname", surnameTextBox.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@contnum", contactTextBox.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@address", addressTextBox.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@jd", jdDateTimePicker.Value)
                If maleRadioButton.Checked = True Then
                    .AddWithValue("@gender", maleRadioButton.Text)
                ElseIf femaleRadioButton.Checked = True Then
                    .AddWithValue("@gender", femaleRadioButton.Text)
                End If
                .AddWithValue("@status", statusComboBox.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dob", dobDateTimePicker.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@pob", burialPlaceTextBox.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@guardname", gNameTextBox.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@guardsname", gSurnameTextBox.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@rel", relationshipTextBox.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@gcontnum", gNumberTextBox.Text)
            End With
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            RefreshDataGridView()
            MessageBox.Show("Member information successfuly updated!", "INFO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            cmd.Dispose()
            conn.Close()
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR12", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: The order of your parameters is off. I'ld suggest to use a DataAdapter to perform the updates.

Comment: The proper way to do this would be to create a `DataTable`, `Fill` it from the database initially using a data adapter if appropriate, bind that to a `BindingSource` and bind that to both the `DataGridView` and the other controls.  When the user enters data into the individual controls, it gets pushed to the `DataTable` and will thus be reflected in the `DataGridView` first.  You then use the same data adapter to `Update` the database with the changes from the `DataTable`.

Comment: You should name your parameters after the columns they apply to so it is obvious if you use the wrong value.

Comment: How @jmcilhinney? I have edited the parameters as suggested.

Comment: That's for you to research.  That's why I posted it in a comment rather than an answer.  What you're doing now is basically all wrong, so you need to go back to the drawing board and learn how to do it the right way.  If you do that and what you try doesn't work, then you can post a new question about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea here for OleDb and Access is to have the parameters added to the Parameters collection in the same order as they appear in the Sql statement.

`.AddWithValue("@rel", relationshipTextBox.Text)` and `.AddWithValue("@gcontnum", gNumberTextBox.Text)` are not in your update statement so they can't be added to the parameters collection. If you alter your Update statement to include these be sure to put them in correct spot when adding them to the Parameters collection.

There is no need to close your connection because the `End Using` line will close and dispose it. It would be better if you did likewise with the `OleDbCommand`. That is, enclose in a Using block.

```
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Update Members set 
        [Name]=@name,
        Middlename=@midname,
        Surname=@sname,
        ContactNumber=@contnum,
        Address=@address,
        DOB=@dob,
        Gender=@gender,
        [Status]=@status,
        JoinDate=@jd,
        POB=@pob,
        [Guardian Name]=@guardname,
        [Guardian Surname]=@guardsname,
        Relationship=@rel,
        GuardNumber=@gcontnum 
        where TKBS_ID=@tkbsid", conn)
    With cmd.Parameters
        .AddWithValue("@name", nameTextBox.Text)
        .AddWithValue("@midname", middleNameTextBox.Text)
        .AddWithValue("@sname", surnameTextBox.Text)
        .AddWithValue("@contnum", contactTextBox.Text)
        .AddWithValue("@address", addressTextBox.Text)
        .AddWithValue("@dob", dobDateTimePicker.Value)
        If maleRadioButton.Checked = True Then
            .AddWithValue("@gender", maleRadioButton.Text)
        ElseIf femaleRadioButton.Checked = True Then
            .AddWithValue("@gender", femaleRadioButton.Text)
        End If
        .AddWithValue("@status", statusComboBox.Text)
        .AddWithValue("@jd", jdDateTimePicker.Value)
        .AddWithValue("@pob", burialPlaceTextBox.Text)
        .AddWithValue("@guardname", gNameTextBox.Text)
        .AddWithValue("@guardsname", gSurnameTextBox.Text)
        .AddWithValue("@tkbsid", tkbsIDTextBox.Text)
    End With
```

I must mention that `.AddWithValue` is not the best way to do this. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications

The preferred method is the `.Add(parameterName As String, OleDbType As OleDBType, Size As Integer).Value = yourValue`

Comment: Thank you so much, the order of parameters was something I overlooked. My code is now working perfectly after just rearranging the parameters. 

Thanks for the links you have provided of which I have learnt a lot from them. But on changing `.AddWithValue` to use `.Add(parameterName As String, OleDbType As OleDBType, Size As Integer).Value = yourValue`, my VS 2019 says its a depleted method to use. It suggests this method:  `AddWithValue(String parameterName, Object value)`. See [link] (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202).